# xml - validate combination of attributes for given element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

i have xml similar to below.

```
<Map>
<MapItem name="firstName" value="john" />
<MapItem name="middleName" value="q" />
<MapItem name="lastName" value="public" />
<MapItem name="phone" value="123-456-7890" />
<MapItem name="ssn" value="123-45-6789" />
<MapItem name="email" value="john@email.com" />
</Map>
```

I would like to come up with a single xsd which can validate the values of the attributes for each `MapItem`.

**Example:**

- middleName = single character
- phone = some regex pattern
- ssn = some other regex pattern
- etc.

**Is this possible (with only a single xsd)?**

**NOTE:**  currently I am using xslt to transform this xml into a more element based structure, which I can validate easily; but i need to do this without any xslt transform.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, XSD Schemas do not support conditional validation. You will not be able to perform the validation you're looking for using an XSD schema.

You're already using one solution which is an XSLT transform. You could also perform the validation using XSLT in one-step where the output from the XSLT transform would be a listing of the validation errors.

I also found a [link for you on the oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/ftopic1664.html#5297) site that talks about a method using Schemtron and/or a Relax NG schema.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks for the link. i had already looked into those options but ruled them out.  unfortunately, it has to be done with only xsd, as "they" don't want to re-write any code to accommodate Schematron or RelaxNG. at this rate, "they" may not have a choice.

Comment: If you are in control of the format of this XML, perhaps you can convince "them" to change the format of this XML to use elements instead of attributes.